# writing a findbugs detector that knows if a method argument is of type Throwable

Tags: java, code-analysis, static-analysis, findbugs

I'm writing a Findbugs detector, based on an OpcodeStackDetector, that looks at all calls to a Java method with a signature like this:

```
void foo(Object...args)
```

It should report a bug if one of the args is of type Throwable or any of its descendents.

How do I get the list of references to the method call that represent the arguments, and then determine if the Class of each argument is a subtype of java.lang.Throwable?

Comment: There exists a Eclipse plugin http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/downloads.html and it's source is available - so take a look?

Comment: I've downloaded the findbugs source code and searching for an answer, but I can't find same.

Answer (score 0):

I can see that OpcodeStackDetector accumulates the stack, so when you see a method call operation in the detect (one of the INVOKEVIRTUAL, INVOKESPECIAL, etc...) the top of the stack should contain the reference to the array of Objects.

Findbugs includes the ASM and BCEL libraries for understanding the byte code, so it should be possible to bridge from the reference to the actual array in memory and somehow get the list of object references from the array. From there you can use ASM/BCEL to verify the type of each reference.

How you do that is puzzling me as well.